# Trying to nunit test enterprise logging

Tags: c#, logging, nunit, enterprise-library

I'm trying to nunit test enterprise logging to proove creating of log etnries etc..

I cant seem to get it to work-  I get an error the config section for loggin can not be found in config source - I think this has something to do with the fact that this is a wpf and the app config isnt being started when i run an nunit test from a class. Any thoughts?

```
 namespace Nunit
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class NunitTests
    {
        string Path = @"C:\Users\dani\bin\Debug\trace.log";



        [Test]
        public void TestLogCreation()
        {}
}
```

Comment: Is the App.config in your unit tests project configured properly? Has it all the configuration needed to log the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier way to accomplish this would be to create an app.config file within the Nunit project and copy the contents over - works perfectly

Comment: That is always possible. But while unit testing a piece of code there should not be a dependency on any external component. In that case it becomes an integration testing. That's why you were receiving an error while reading a config entry because you used a code which is dependent on external factors.  Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

When you run NUnit executable, it tries to look into it's own config file for any configuration entries which it can't find. After that it searches for configuration entries in machine.config file. There also it does not find the config entries, hence it gives the error.

You can fix this by putting config entries in machine.config file.

But it would not be a right way to unit test. You have to provide fake class for reading configuration entries rather than reading actual config values from config file.

machine.config file can be found at below mentioned paths:

**32 bit**

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\config\machine.config
```

**64 bit**

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\machine.config
```

**EDIT**

```
public interface IConfigReader
{
    string ReadConfigEntry(string keyName);
}

public class ConfigReader : IConfigReader
{
    public string ReadConfigEntry(string keyName)
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[keyName];
    }
}

public class FakeConfigReader : IConfigReader
{
    public string ReadConfigEntry(string keyName)
    {
        string configValue = string.Empty;

        //provide dummy implementation instead of reading actual .config file

        return configValue;
    }
}
```

Now create instances of `IConfigReader` interface. In actual code use  `ConfigReader` implementation to read config values and while unit testing use `FakeConfigReader` implementation. In `FakeConfigReader` you can return any arbitrary hard coded value from `ReadConfigEntry` method.

Comment: @user3223507 I have edited my answer. Please check if it is useful to or not.

Comment: Thank you - Im fairly new to c# so have copied yoru code in but not sure where i woudl apply things - Ive edited abovce to include my code would yo umind helping me just a bit more to show how i implement that

Comment: hi @user3223507, I have looked into your code. There are various ways to use my code. In your actual implementation you can create a parameterized constructor accepting `IConfigReader` as the parameter. In actual implementation use `ConfigReader` and in unit test method pass an object of `FakeConfigReader`.